# I reach a half-dead end when trying to find the minimum possible value of an equation

Tags: problem-solving

I have the equation  $x^2 + 4xy + 5y^2 - 4x - 6y +7$ and I'm supposed to transform it to look like this:

$[x + 2(y - 1)]^2 + (y + 1)^2 + 2$

First I transformed it into:

$x^2 + 4x(y - 1) + 5y^2 - 6y + 7$

and then completed the square for $x$:

$[x + 2(y - 1)]^2 - 4(y - 1)^2 + 5y^2 - 6y + 7$

which sort of looks like the first part of the **answer**, however when I complete the square for the second part:

$[x + 2(y - 1)]^2 - 4(y - 1)^2 + 5(y - 6/5)^2 - 36/25 + 7$

which seems wrong and I can't get it into the state of the answer from here.I have this $- 4(y - 1)^2$ that is ruining it for me.What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try expanding the problem part first, collecting like terms, then complete the square:
\begin{align*}
&[x + 2(y - 1)]^2 - 4(y - 1)^2 + 5y^2 - 6y + 7 \\
&= [x + 2(y - 1)]^2 - 4(y^2 - 2y + 1) + 5y^2 - 6y + 7 \\
&= [x + 2(y - 1)]^2 - 4y^2 + 8y - 4 + 5y^2 - 6y + 7 \\
&= [x + 2(y - 1)]^2 + y^2 + 2y + 3 \\
&= [x + 2(y - 1)]^2 + (y + 1)^2 + 2 \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^2 + 4xy + 5y^2 - 4x - 6y +7=c$

On rearrangement we have $\displaystyle x^2+4x(y-1)+5y^2-6y+7-c=0$ which is a Quadrtic Equation in $x$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e.,  $\displaystyle \{4(y-1)\}^2-4\cdot1(5y^2-6y+7-c)\ge0$

$\displaystyle\implies c\ge y^2+2y+3=(y+1)^2+2\ge2$  the equality occurs if $y=-1$

A similar method is used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555235/the-number-of-integral-solutions-for-the-equation-x-y-x2-y2-xy).

Comment: @DEIMOS, how about this?

Answer (score 0):

When you completed the first square, expand the remaining [developing (y-1)^2]; this becomes (y^2+ 2 y + 3). Complete the square again and you get (y+1)^2 + 2.